# Rails routing for an online shop, eg: /somecategory/someitem, causes issues with gets for /javascripts/all.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm having issues with rails routing for an online shop. I want routes eg:

```
/cars/camaro
/bikes/nightrod
```

To achieve this, i've got this in routes.rb:

```
match '/:cat/:item', :to => 'browse#item'
```

It works fine, as in i can browse all good. But it causes issues with http GET's for (mostly i've noticed) '/javascripts/all.js' - these appear to be being routed to my browse#item action wrongly, which crashes because it cannot find that category or product.

Can someone suggest how i can solve this? Through better routing? I'd rather not give up my cool url's, but a last resort is, i guess, to route to /browse/category/product...

FWIW i'm hosting in heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you've now created a default path for everything, which isn't a great solution. I haven't actually tried this, but I think :constraints might be what you're looking for... i.e.

```
match '/:cat/:item', :to => 'browse#item', :constraints => { :cat => /(cars|bikes|trucks|vans)/ }
```

but any time a cat changes, you'll have to add that there...

Alternatively if your categories are stored in the DB, you can try:

```
match '/:cat/:item', :to => 'browse#item', :constraints => { :cat => /#{Category.all.map{|c|c.name}.join('|')}/ }
```